# Is there a tweak to show a percentage in the battery icon?

Tags: 11.10, battery, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set the power indicator to show battery percentage instead of time remaining?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2283/can-i-set-the-power-indicator-to-show-battery-percentage-instead-of-time-remaini)

I'm use to not having to click on the battery icon to see what my battery percentage is, like on my Android phone. Is there a tweak/mod/hack to do this on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: See http://pad.lv/811777 where this was reported and it was thought that users would rather see the time remaining than see a percentage, despite what other desktops do.

Comment: Are you using default unity shell or did you installed Gnome shell?