# Show battery as percentage, not time?

Tags: 11.10, gui, customization, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a tweak to show a percentage in the battery icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70798/is-there-a-tweak-to-show-a-percentage-in-the-battery-icon)

I just recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 (I've used older versions, but I'm still a noob), and (almost) everything works fine. I just want to know if there's a way to show battery remaining as a percentage, not as time remaining. The battery icon says Batter(0:41 to charge, but I just want to know what percent full my battery is. Power Settings only lets me choose whether to suspend/hibernate/etc. in certain situations. Where would I find an option to change this?

As an aside, I also can't find where to change or even add a screen saver. The older versions I used (10.04 I think) had tons of options to tweak everything (from the GUI), where did they all go?

Also, I've seen other answers saying to install Docky, but I switched from OSX and love the dock system in 11.10.